# Insert duplicate row in table in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, html-table, react-hooks

I am new to react. I have a requirement in which if user click on `+` symbol the same `row` should be inserted just below.. I am not able to think the logic.

for generating table I have written below code. I dont know what I should write to create `duplicate`.

```
{response.map((certificate: Certificate) => {
  return (
    <tr key={certificate.certificateNo}>
      <td>{certificate.certificateNo}</td>
      <td>{certificate.sponser}</td>
      <td>{certificate.protoColNo}</td>
      <td>{certificate.startDate}</td>
      <td>{certificate.endDate}</td>
      <td>{certificate.noOfSubjects}</td>
      <td>{certificate.country}</td>
      <td>{certificate.requestStatus}</td>
      <td>
        <div className="btn-group mr-2">
          <Link
            to={`/certificates/${certificate.certificateNo}/edit`}
            className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
            <i className="bi bi-pencil"></i>
          </Link>
          <Link
            to={`/certificates/${certificate.certificateNo}/edit`}
            className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
            <i className="bi bi-plus-square"></i>
          </Link>
          <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
            -
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
            <i className="bi bi-x-circle"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
            <i className="bi bi-search"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
})}
```

As suggested by `Samet` below code is working. But I am passing index manually. like I have passed `0` .how to make it dynamic?

```
const copy = (index: number) => {
    const duplicatRow = response[index];
    const firstPart = response.slice(0, index + 1);
    const secondPart = response.slice(index + 1, response.length);
    const newData = [...firstPart, duplicatRow, ...secondPart];
    setResponse(newData);
};



{response.map((certificate: Certificate) => {
                                    return (
                                     <tr key={certificate.certificateNo}>
                                      <td>{certificate.certificateNo}</td>
                                      <td>{certificate.sponser}</td>
                                      <td>{certificate.protoColNo}</td>
                                      <td>{certificate.startDate}</td>
                                      <td>{certificate.endDate}</td>
                                      <td>{certificate.noOfSubjects}</td>
                                      <td>{certificate.country}</td>
                                      <td>{certificate.requestStatus}</td>
                                      <td>
                                            <button className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" onClick={() =>copy(0)} >
                                                <i className="bi bi-plus-square"></i>
                                            </button>
```

[image]

Comment: Are u saying new after clicking the plus button, a new row appears at the end of the table or it has to be right next row of current row?

Comment: right next row of current row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this in two steps:

**1. Capture in which row the button is clicked**

This is pretty straightforward. On the onClick method of your button, you can either receive a unique identifier for the row, probably the id field of the row data, or receive the index of the row in your data. I'd go with the second one and pass the index to my `duplicateRow` method.

**2. Duplicate the row**

This is where the magic will happen. You will receive the index, find the row data at that index, then slice your array into two pieces:

- From 0 to `index + 1`
- From `index + 1` to `data.length`

Your duplicated value will go right in between. Now you can update the state with the new data.

Here is the example code you can modify for your component:

```
function duplicateRow(index: number) {
  const duplicateRow = data[index];
  const firstPart = data.slice(0, index + 1);
  const secondPart = data.slice(index + 1, data.length);

  const newData = [...firstPart, duplicateData, ...secondPart];

  setData(newData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Samet. your code is working properly. just one more thing. How to pass index dynamically. I have passed the code above in which I have passed 0 and tested.

Comment: It worked. I took like this response.map((certificate: Certificate,index:number)    . is it correct Samet?

Comment: Your `map` method takes a callback function, right? The second parameter of that function gives you the index value of each item. You can receive it like so: `.map((certificate: Certificate, index: number) => {` and pass `index` to your `copy` function.

Comment: ya sure Samet...it worked in this way...thank you so much. you made my task much easier.